# what is the meaning of this error Couldn't find string in telnet output ()

Tags: networking, testing, tcl, automated-tests, telnet

I am geeting this error message " error Couldn't find string in telnet output () " while running a test plan using TCL.What is the meaning of this error and why i am getting this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should mean exactly what it says.

You are expecting a certain string to be returned from the thing you're testing (such as `'login: '`), and that string is not appearing (maybe you're getting `'Log In:'` instead, for example).

You need to figure out what's *actually* coming out and adjust your expectations accordingly.